# Extjs sorting store by alphanumeric field

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I've got a bunch of records whose names are like "Itemtype #", and when they are outputted into a tree view, they're sorted incorrectly, like so:

- Item 1
- Item 10
- Item 11
- Item 12
- Item 13
- Item 2
- Item 3
- Item 4

My model fields are defined as follows, and I am sorting on "Name":

```
fields: [
  { name: 'Id', defaultValue: 0, type: 'int', mapping: 'Id' },
  { name: 'Name', defaultValue: '', type: 'string', mapping: 'Name', sortType: Ext.data.SortTypes.asUCString },
  { name: 'Type', defaultValue: 0, type: 'int', mapping: 'Type' },
  { name: 'CreationDate', type: 'date', mapping: 'CreationDate' }
],
```

Can anybody point me in the right direction? I'm using extjs 4.0.5

Comment: Well the sorting callback isn't working properly likely due to an override somewhere else in our app, but it is the correct way to do this. We're sorting the sql now instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling [TreeStore.sort](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.util.Sortable-method-sort) with a sorter config with [a sorting callback](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.util.Sorter-cfg-sorterFn). A simple field sort won't do in this case because the naive alpha sort isn't what you want. The example at the top of the [Ext.util.Sorter doc](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.util.Sorter) shows how to do it in a store, but you can just as easily add it to the `sorters` param of your model.

Answer (score 16):

In store you have to set up how the data will display by sorters property:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
  .
  .
  .
  remoteSort: false, //true for server sorting
  sorters: [{
     property: 'Name',
     direction: 'DESC' // or 'ASC'
   }],
  .
  .
  .

})
```

Comment: I am doing this but getting the result described above. Thanks anyway.